# php pdo prepared exec statement only if value given

Tags: php, pdo

I have a simple PDO prepared statement with an exec statement.

I am running into a problem that I only am supposed to pass in the parameters if a value is provided otherwise, it needs to not be provided or be default (not as a string).

is there a way to change the exec statement to work either way? Either only pass the parameters if there is a post value for it, or how do I send in default?

```
 exec ******  @userId=? ,@Gender=?  ,@MinAge=?  ,@MaxAge=?  ,@AppId=?"  );
$stmt->bindParam(1, $_POST['username']);    
$stmt->bindParam(2, $_POST['gender'] ); 
$stmt->bindParam(3, $_POST['minAge']);  
$stmt->bindParam(4, $_POST['maxAge']);  
$stmt->bindParam(5,  $_POST['appid']);  
 $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Show the exact query

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value in the php if its possible to use default value in your query, unless you have to dynamically create the where clause by checking you POST values empty or not and then bind the corresponding param. Would be easy if you use namedParams like :userId

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass `null` as a default value if the value hasn't been entered (assuming `null` is OK), you can just test the input for not being empty and pass null when it is empty...

```
$stmt->bindParam(1, !empty($_POST['username'])? $_POST['username']:null);
```

You can change the `null` to be any other value, the principle is the same.